# Horizontal line in table cells

Tags: tables, diagrams

Is there a simple way to draw a horizontal line in one (or more, but not all) cells in a table, as shown in these examples (SQL database diagrams).

[image]

[image]

(The line indicates "primary key".)

Something like `cline` but with automatic spacing.

Comment: My suggestion is using ‘clip’ of TikZ!

Comment: @BlackMild it must be possible in `tabular`, `tabularx` etc also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hhline](https://ctan.org/pkg/hhline):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, hhline}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
employee_id (PK)& name & ... \\
\hhline{|=|-|-|}

&&\\
\hline
&&\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```